# Canonical structures in ssreflect

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm trying to deal with canonical structures in ssreflect. There are 2 pieces of code that I took from [here](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/contribs/files/Ssreflect/v8.4/Ssreflect.fintype.html).

I will bring pieces for the bool and the option types.

```
Section BoolFinType.

  Lemma bool_enumP : Finite.axiom [:: true; false]. Proof. by case. Qed.
  Definition bool_finMixin := Eval hnf in FinMixin bool_enumP.
  Canonical bool_finType := Eval hnf in FinType bool bool_finMixin.
  Lemma card_bool : #|{: bool}| = 2. Proof. by rewrite cardT enumT unlock. Qed.

End BoolFinType.

Section OptionFinType.

  Variable T : finType.
  Notation some := (@Some _) (only parsing).

  Local Notation enumF T := (Finite.enum T).

  Definition option_enum := None :: map some (enumF T).

  Lemma option_enumP : Finite.axiom option_enum.
  Proof. by case => [x|]; rewrite /= count_map (count_pred0, enumP). Qed.

  Definition option_finMixin := Eval hnf in FinMixin option_enumP.
  Canonical option_finType := Eval hnf in FinType (option T) option_finMixin.

  Lemma card_option : #|{: option T}| = #|T|.+1.
  Proof. by rewrite !cardT !enumT {1}unlock /= !size_map. Qed.

End OptionFinType.
```

Now, suppose I have a function f from finType to Prop.

```
Variable T: finType.
Variable f: finType -> Prop.

Goal f T. (* Ok *)
Goal f bool. (* Not ok *)
Goal f (option T). (* Not ok *)
```

In the last two cases I get the following error:

> The term "bool/option T" has type "Set/Type" while it is expected to have type "finType".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Canonical structures get triggered on certain unification problems to provide a solution, usually when the projection of a record is involved [see the manual] For your particular case, Coq won't detect the particular unification problem thus the canonical mechanism won't act. You can retrieve the `finType` instance associated to bool using `Goal f [finType of bool]`, see the implementation of this notation for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The instance search for canonical structures is a bit counter intuitive in these cases.  Suppose that you have the following things:

- a structure type `S`, and a type `T`;
- a field `proj : S -> T` of `S`;
- an element `x : T`; and
- an element `st : S` that has been declared as canonical, such that `proj st` is defined as `x`.

In your example, we would have:

- `S = finType`
- `T = Type`
- `proj = Finite.sort`
- `x = bool`
- `st = bool_finType`.

Canonical structure search is triggered *only* in the following case: when the type-checking algorithm is trying to find a value to validly fill in the hole in the equation `proj _ = x`. Then, it will use `st : S` to fill in this hole. In your example, you expected the algorithm to understand that `bool` can be used as `finType`, by transforming it into `bool_finType`, which is not quite what is described above.

To make Coq infer what you want, you need to use a unification problem of that form.  For instance,

```
Variable P : finType -> Prop.
Check ((fun (T : finType) (x : T) => P T) _ true).
```

What is going on here?  Remember that `Finite.sort` is declared as a coercion from `finType` to `Type`, so `x : T` really means `x : Finite.sort T`.  When you apply the `fun` expression to `true : bool`, Coq has to find a solution for `Finite.sort _ = bool`.  It then finds `bool_finType`, because it was declared as canonical.  So the element of `bool` is what triggers the search, but not quite `bool` itself.

As ejgallego pointed out, this pattern is so common that ssreflect provides the special `[finType of ...]` syntax.  But it might still be useful to understand what is going on under the hood.